# Rake get directory name in file glob

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

If a Rake File exists with the following code:

```
file 'assets/*/map.a' => ['map.b', 'map.c'] do
    # Code goes here...
end
```

I want to know what the name of the directory in the glob is (instead of the file). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file 'assets/*/map.a' => ['map.b', 'map.c'] do |path|
    File.basename(File.dirname(path))
end
```